# hist() main title from list name

Tags: r, histogram

I am plotting 7 histograms from a a list and want to update the title of the histogram depending on the position of the list.

This is what I got so far but I am getting the following error when executing the script.

> Error in item_df[df] : invalid subscript type 'list'

```
full_df <- read.csv("filename")

item_df <- split(full_df, full_df$PIA_ITEM)

par(mfrow = c(3,3)) # 3 rows and 3 columns
for (df in item_df) {
  hist(df[[7]], breaks=9,  main = paste("Histogram of", names(item_df[df])))
}
```

The error points at my attempt of using the looping index to draw the list name position

```
main = paste("Histogram of", names(item_df[df]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As data is not provided, I add an example with dummy data and then a possible sketch for your problem. Based on your code I think you are trying to add as title the value of `PIA_ITEM` and plotting the variable in position 7. This dummy example works for `iris`:

```
full_df <- iris

item_df <- split(full_df, full_df$Species)

par(mfrow = c(3,3)) # 3 rows and 3 columns
for (i in 1:length(item_df)) 
{
  hist(item_df[[i]]$Sepal.Length, breaks=9,  
       main = paste("Histogram of", unique(item_df[[i]]$Species)),
       xlab = 'x')
}
```

And produces:

[image]

And the code for your problem should be something like this:

```
full_df <- read.csv("filename.csv")

item_df <- split(full_df, full_df$PIA_ITEM)

par(mfrow = c(3,3)) # 3 rows and 3 columns
for (i in 1:length(item_df)) 
{
  hist(item_df[[i]][,7], breaks=9,  
       main = paste("Histogram of", unique(item_df[[i]]$PIA_ITEM)),
       xlab = 'x')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapt this example:

```
item_df <- split(mtcars[, 1], mtcars$cyl)

par(mfrow = c(1, 3))
for (i in names(item_df)){
  hist(item_df[[ i ]], main = paste("Histogram of", i))
}
```

[image]